# Is CAS (Centralized Authentication Service) dependent on cookie?

Tags: cas

If CAS is based on cookies, then will it work after disabling cookies? And can we manage CAS SSO using session management API?

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are required for SSO. Not for authentication.